# Autocompletion didn't highlight in vscode python for some variable

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, autocomplete

that variabel is return `np.ndarray` when i `print(type(im))`.

But my vscode didn't show autocompletion when i'm trying to access one of method in `np.ndarray` with start using `dot` like `im.<method>`. While It work's when I try `np.ndarray().<method>`

[image]
[image]

My Full Code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# READ IMAGE
im = cv2.imread('./sampel/fotopendaftaran.jpg',cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED) # IMREAD_GRAYSCALE berarti warna abu-abu

im.round()
np.ndarray(shape=(2,2)).round()

# DISPLAY IMAGE
cv2.imshow('Contoh',im)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# WRITE IMAGE
cv2.imwrite('./sampel/output.jpg',im)
```

Comment: I think it's because `OpenCV` library does not provide type annotations for `cv2.imread()` function yet. If you hover your mouse over `imread` in VS code, you will find that the return type of `imread` is `Any`. So, VS code was not able to infer `im` variable as an instance of `ndarray`. For type annotations, see [PEP 484](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/).

Comment: But can we force cv2 display anotation? In another program language we can tell explicitly what type of a variabel so vscode will recognize that type data

Comment: Other language definition types are also written for languages. Vscode is just an editor.